# Metaphorical reference to someone bad to doing good and being praised more than a good person

Tags: idioms, expressions

I'd like to point out the following phenomenon that frequently occurs in the daily life. Take a mischief, culprit, someone unreliable and well-known to be a lousy piece of manure. Basically a bad person. When they stop with their misdeeds and do something good, the contrast between expectations and actuality cause such a dissonance that they often can market the improvement widely and with lots of appreciation.

While it's obvious that the good deed should be rewarded as the changed achieved is welcome and worth encouraging, there's a difference between that and the reaction an oppositely minded person. A person who is reliable, don't horse around, does well upon others etc. will, of course, be appreciated for those actions but the level of gratitude and praise tends to be far lesser, down to non-existing.

It's especially commonly noticeable in schools where the typical *bad boy* might get a lot of positive attention for doing a slight change for the better, whereas the typical *good girl* might take substantial reprimand for simply not upholding a high standard at a few occasions. (The reference to gender being irrelevant here, I only used those as a coined terms - the *good girl* might be a male.)

I'd like to allude the above situation, rather implying it by an expression than describing it bluntly by direct description.

I'm talking about a method like saying *november-may situation* or *doing raindance*. The first one being a reference to a romantic relationship of with a considerable age difference. The second one being a reference to the rain being annoyingly imminent right after one has washed the car.

Comment: Can you say why you suppose this has an answer?  If a writer needs a metaphor, usually they have create one themself. Most situations don't have standard metaphors.

Comment: @Konrad Villersten Does that expression exist in your native language?

Comment: I really like how detailed this is ...

Comment: @JamesK I'm not sure if I completely agree on that point. If we consider the fact that most of our lives consist of situations similar to previous/others' so, in fact, most of what happens will have a conventional reference, not rarely even an idiom or proverb. That being said, I agree that this particular maybe case hasn't. Would you like to suggest one?

Comment: I will if you will.  "It's just like when Sophie Briggs won the conduct medal at school".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty As far I'm aware, no. In fact, that's what I'm looking for in the end. Since I haven't found one in Vikingish, I asked here hoping that it's going to give me an idea or that I could introduce the English version as ours.

Comment: @JamesK I'm not familiar with Sophie Briggs so I googled the name. Regrettably, I have to admit that you lost me there. Would you be willing to elaborate your point? I feel kind of dumb.

Comment: No, she was just a girl at school.  I made up the reference. But your situation is just like this...

Comment: @JamesK I don't follow, sorry. The situation I described is very commonly occurring in the daily life, definitely not limited to school environment. Obviously, I haven't explained it sufficiently clearly for you to see my point. Not sure how to elaborate and since I don't recognize the reaction, I guess it might be better to stop here. Thank you for trying, though. I appreciate the effort.